# rpy2 pass : in function arguments

Tags: python, rpy2

I am facing an issue when trying to execute the r code below with python rpy2.

```
from rpy2.robjects import r    
import rpy2.robjects as ro    
from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter      
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri       
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr      

stats = importr("stats")

with localconverter(ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):  
         Rdataframe2 = ro.conversion.py2rpy(dtw)

 rdism = r["as.dist"](Rdataframe2)      
 ttclust = r.hclust(rdism)     
 ttclusterange = r.cutree(ttclust, k='1:3')
```

I can't find a way to pass the argument `k="1:3"` in the `cutree` function.

I keep receiving an error message stating

```
""elements of 'k' must be between 1 and %d",  :
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

it seems that I can't find the right syntax to execute the last line.

Can someone please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

The `1:3` expression is meant to generate a vector of `c(1, 2, 3)` in R. However, you are not evaluating it in R but passing it as a string/character `'1:3'` using rpy2. Try passing an equivalent list `[1, 2, 3]` instead, or using `list(range(1, 3 + 1))`. This is:

```
r.cutree(ttclust, k=list(range(1, 3 + 1)))
```

Comment: thank you very much for the advice, it work fine now.

Comment: The answer works fine. Recent releases of rpy2 (3.4.x, IIRC) have added an additional option in the form of a convenience function to help blend R snippets (as unevaluated R language objects) into Python code. `r.cutree(ttclust, k=ro.rl('1:3'))` should also work.